# Regex with conditional replacement

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex to validate phone numbers with the following criteria:

> Return the input as-is if it's fewer than 7 digits. Otherwise, remove the first character if it is a 1 or 0. If we haven't returned yet and the number is < 10 digits, return it. If it's >= 10 digits, return the last 7.

This is performance-critical code converted from coded conditional statements so ideally it can be done in a single regex. I managed to hack together something that got me close but I'm having some trouble meeting all criteria without further breaking things.

(Spaces are just to break things up since there's a lot here).

```
var pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\A[01]?) ([0-9]{1,9}) (?![0-9]) | (?:[01]?) (?<=\A[01]?) (?:[0-9]{3,}) ([0-9]{7}) (.*)", "$1$2");
return pattern.replaceAll(phoneNum);
```

This passes all the test strings I gave it except it doesn't remove the 0 or 1 like it should if they exist as the first character of strings of length 7+.

```
// Returns input as-is if fewer than 7 digits
    555123  --> 555123    Success

// If 7+ digits remove the first character if it is a 1 or 0
   1234567  --> 234567    Failure, returned 1234567

// If we haven't returned yet and the number is < 10 digits, return
   5551212  --> 5551212   Success

// If it's >= 10 digits, return the last 7
5551234567  --> 1234567   Success
```

Comment: Can you please provide some match/fail testcase?

Comment: If it is performance critical, regex might not be a good solution, as this definitely requires some look-forward stuff. A traditional if-else might be more efficient.

Comment: @namgold Updated with cases

Comment: I agree with Jai: a regex might be overkill here. If you already know the string only contains numbers then simple string and character based operations would be way more efficient.

Comment: @Thomas Alright. Ideally I could benchmark both options but I rarely have to touch regex so I'll take the word of you fine folk. Though I'd like to hope there's a good reason my more senior coworkers chose to have all the logic rewritten as 100+-character expressions...

Comment: Well, regex can come in handy if you have to do complex checks. However there are also devs who like regex way too much or apply them to the wrong kind of problem (not everything is a regular problem space, e.g. programming or scripting languages, and thus not a good fit for regex).

Comment: I would say Regex definitely looks "cooler" and "more professional." In almost all situations, regex is going to be slower than traditional conditional statements. I've seen a good use-case for regex though. That is when performance isn't very critical, and when you are using it as a validation logic which could change over time. In this case, putting the regex expression in a config or property file, and having the code to read from that would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java isn't my forte, but as people have mentioned regex might not be the right solution to your question. Just in case you are still interested in a regular expression, I think the following covers all your criteria:

```
^(?:(?=\d{7,9}$)[01]?|\d*(?=\d{7}$)|)(\d+$)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oNeFIG/5/)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group.

  - `(?=\d{7,9}$`- A positive lookahead to assert position when there are 7-9 digits up to end string ancor.
  - `[01]?` - Optionally capture a zero or one.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `\d*` - Capture as many digits but untill:
  - `(?=\d{7}$)` - Positive lookahead for 7 digits untill end string ancor.
  - `|` - Or: Match nothing.
  - `)` - Close non-capturing group.
- `(\d+$)` - Capture all remaining digits in 1st capture group until end string ancor.

Comment: Much cleaner than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

A replaceAll with a lambda might be sufficient, having the disadvantage that the lambda is a bit slower, though the regex faster. It is more maintainable, certainly for real-world business logic. Just time the result in a micro-benchmark.

```
var pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+)\\b");
return pattern.matcher(phoneNum).replaceAll(mr -> {
    String digits = mr.group(1);
    if (digits.length() < 7) { // Or better \\d{7, 20}
        return digits;
    }
    if (digits.startsWith("0") || digits.startsWith(1)) { // Can be optimized
        digits = digits.substring(1);
    }
    if (digits >= 10) {
        digits = digits.substring(digits.length() - 7);
    }
    return digits;
});
```

Your test cases should be kept as unit tests, as such business rules tend to change "slightly" - especially if you prefer a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the if version, as suggested in comments, I've also added your tests as unit tests:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class SomeClass {

    public String correctPhoneNumber(String number) {
        if (number.length() >= 7 && (number.startsWith("0") || number.startsWith("1"))) {
            return number.substring(1);
        }
        if (number.length() >= 10) {
            return number.substring(number.length() - 7);
        }
        return number;
    }

    @Test
    void correctPhoneNumberTest() {
        SomeClass objectToTest = new SomeClass();

        assertEquals("555123", objectToTest.correctPhoneNumber("555123"));
        assertEquals("234567", objectToTest.correctPhoneNumber("1234567"));
        assertEquals("5551212", objectToTest.correctPhoneNumber("5551212"));
        assertEquals("1234567", objectToTest.correctPhoneNumber("5551234567"));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The logic reads/looks right, since I'm a Java rooky, is there any way you can include test results like an online ide or something? =) +

Comment: Thanks @JvdV
I have just made it nicer and copy/paste friendly for anyone's IDE, now I will search for an online tester too :)

Comment: Great, I just naïvely copy/pasted it in [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/java10) which then returned an error.

Comment: I think that most of online testers do not have jUnit :/ 
It is probably easier / faster to try it in your local IDE (If you don't have one download IntelliJ community edition, it is free and incredibly powerful).